# what is the correct procedure for building AOSP for a specified device step by step?

Tags: android, build, tablet, android-source, android-build

Actually , I have read completely [Establishing a Build Environment](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) from google source and other steps but I got confused ! .

My tablet runs AOSP (Android 5.1.1_r1, codename : inet_phone_32) , its powered by Intel atom CPU ,
**I really need a developer tells me FULLY , step by step of building AOSP for my tablet.(**there is no program to root the tablet for pulling its android OS , SYSTEM.IMG , BOOT.IMG ,RECOVERY.IMG...)

thank you.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12851362/295004

Answer (score 0):

[Source Code](https://01.org/android-IA)

That's the source code; I'm sure the kernel source code is in there.

Aside from that, when you set up the AOSP source to build, there's an option to build Intel x86 system instead of ARM, using lunch. That source is downloaded with the usual repo sync. So, you now have the kernel and system. For recovery, TWRP would be the easiest to obtain.

Essentially you should read the developers.android.com guide on AOSP building.

Comment: I know i must install repo
openjdk-8-jdk
curl
git
and sync repo to download Android source repository
but what should i do after that ?
what are the steps consequently ?
thx

Comment: Unzip the file from the link above, then move into the source. After that, source build/envsetup.sh, lunch, number option with the x86-eng, build -jX. X for 4 times the amount of threads you have (or anything, but for optimal performance, 4x threads).

Comment: So many files are here ,which one , and i must unzip it to root of building folder 
https://01.org/android-ia/downloads/

Comment: Maybe not necessary, assuming the AOSP source already has the kernels prebuilt. Check around in the source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable Developer options > USB debugging?
If you can't unlock the bootloader via fastboot, then there is no point in wasting time establishing a build environment.

If you can somehow unlock the bootloader then the next thing you would need to obtain is the necessary proprietary binary blobs.